# Call methods of child class in java

Tags: java, inheritance

How to call print*() of all classes in below scenario means call A's printA(), B's printB() and C's printC() inside the main() method.

```
class A
{
  public void printA(){System.out.println("A.printA()");}
}

class B extends A
{
    public void printB(){System.out.println("B.printB()");}
}

class C extends A
{
    public void printC(){System.out.println("C.printC()");}
}
class DemoInheritence
{
    public static void main(String[] str){
        printIt(new A());
        printIt(new B());
        printIt(new C());
    }
    public static void printIt(A a) {
        //Here I wants to call A's printA(), B's printB() and C's printC()
        //So how can I do this
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For you code you could use something like:

```
public static void printIt(A a) {
    if(a instanceof B) {
    ((B)a).printB();
    } else if(a instanceof C) {
       ((C)a).printC();
    } else {
      a.printA(); 
    }

}
```

But this is kinda wrong, you should go with overriding the method in A's child classes, or better yet create an interface that all your classes implement and use that interface in your code.

Comment: Any other solution rather then using 'instanceof '

Comment: @user1041858 if you want to avoid using "instanceof" you should go with overriding the print method, meaning that class A and it's children have a method called print() and it's children override this method (you could even enforce it by making the method and class A abstract). But the best way would be to create an interface with a print method, and make all the classes implement that interface. So each class would have it's version of the print() method. Please tell me if you want me to further explain this.

Comment: @user1041858 if you want to determine if an object is of a particular type, please tell me so I can further explain this.

Answer (score 11):

Usually, you do something like this, it's called overriding:

```
class A
{
  public void print(){System.out.println("A.printA()");}
}

class B extends A
{
    public void print(){System.out.println("B.printB()");}
}

class C extends A
{
    public void print(){System.out.println("C.printC()");}
}
class DemoInheritence
{
    public static void main(String[] str){
        printIt(new A());
        printIt(new B());
        printIt(new C());
    }
    public static void printIt(A a) {
        a.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: But I am not talking about this scenario. My scenario is different

Comment: This answer got heavily upvoted, while the suggestion was too basic/simple and was of no use to the OP..!

Comment: @InfantPro'Aravind' I assume that's because the question was not clear enough. I and the 10 other people misunderstood it

Answer (score 0):

You may use the reflection API, but then you might to make some assumptions. There are at least 2 possibilities:

Solution 1. If print method is called "print[Class name]" you get the method by name:

```
public static void printIt(Object o) {
    Class objectClass = o.getClass();
    try {
        Method printMethod = objectClass.getMethod("print" + objectClass.getName());
        printMethod.invoke(o);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Method print"+objectClass.getName()+"() doesn't exist", e);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Problem calling method print"+objectClass.getName()+"()", e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Method print"+objectClass.getName()+"() is not accessible", e);
    }
}
```

Solution 2. If Every class always declares ONE method you take first method returned by getDeclaredMethod of passed object's class:

```
public static void printIt(Object o) {
    Class objectClass = o.getClass();
    try {
        Method printMethod = objectClass.getDeclaredMethods()[0];
        printMethod.invoke(o);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Problem calling method print"+objectClass.getName()+"()", e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Method print"+objectClass.getName()+"() is not accessible", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not abuse reflection (java.lang.reflect) in this trivial case, especially in production code, it is slow, ugly, too verbose, and deprecated.

Comment: I would agree, for that exact problem, but my solution is more generic then checking of instanceof, which might be not suitable if D, E etc. classes are added. Than you have to modify also printIt method which might not be obvious until runtime and that is error prone.

Comment: And first af all, the given case in this question is not a correct architecture. But sometimes you have to work in weird ecosystem.

Comment: One more, why reflection is deprecated in your opinion (I can agree with other drawbacks)?

Comment: I will only answer your last comment. java.lang.reflect should be replace by java.lang.invoke, as stated in The well grounded Java Developer by B. Evans and M. Verburg on item 5.2. Some reading regarding the subject: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/package-summary.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/invoke./MethodHandle.html